# Primefaces dataTable in Jsf Composite Component and rowSelectCheckBox event

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I have a composite component with DataTable using primefaces.

```
 <cc:interface>
     <cc:attribute name="amountToAllocate" />
     <cc:attribute name="transactionsToAllocate" />
     <cc:attribute name="selectedTransactions" />
     <cc:attribute name="allocateAutoUpdateId" />
     <cc:attribute name="amountAllocated" />
     <cc:attribute name="allocationRemaining" />
     <cc:attribute name="rowSelectUpdateId" />
     <cc:attribute name="allocateAutoListener"
                   method-signature="void action()"  />
     <cc:attribute name="toggleSelectListener"
                   method-signature="void action(org.primefaces.event.ToggleSelectEvent)" />
     <cc:attribute name="selectRowListener"
                   method-signature="void action(org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent)"  />
     <cc:attribute name="unselectRowListener" 
                   method-signature="void action(org.primefaces.event.UnselectEvent)"  />
</cc:interface> 
<cc:implementation>
<p:dataTable value="#{cc.attrs.transactionsToAllocate}"
    var="transaction"
    selection="#{cc.attrs.selectedTransactions}"
    rowKey="#{transaction.transactionId}" >
    <p:ajax event="toggleSelect"
        listener="#{cc.attrs.toggleSelectListener}"
        update="#{cc.attrs.rowSelectUpdateId}"  />
    <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox"
            listener="#{cc.attrs.selectRowListener}"
            update="#{cc.attrs.rowSelectUpdateId}" />
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox"
            listener="#{cc.attrs.unselectRowListener}"
            update="#{cc.attrs.rowSelectUpdateId}" />
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple"
        style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
    <p:column headerText="Reference">
        #{transaction.reference}
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Invoice Date">
        <h:outputText value="#{transaction.transactionDate}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yy" />
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</cc:implementation>
```

And its implementation here:------------------------

```
<h:panelGroup id="alloc">
    <ezcomp:transactionAllocation  amountToAllocate="#{apCreditNoteTransactionBean.transaction.value}"  
        transactionsToAllocate="#{apCreditNoteTransactionBean.transactionAllocationInvoiceData.unallocatedTransactions}"
        selectedTransactions="#{apCreditNoteTransactionBean.transactionAllocationInvoiceData.selectedUnallocatedTransactions}"
        allocateAutoListener="#{apCreditNoteTransactionBean.autoAllocateTransactionToSelectedTransaction}"
        allocateAutoUpdateId=":#{p:component('alloc')}"
        amountAllocated="#{apCreditNoteTransactionBean.transactionAllocationInvoiceData.amountAllocated}"
        allocationRemaining="#{apCreditNoteTransactionBean.transaction.value-apCreditNoteTransactionBean.transactionAllocationInvoiceData.amountAllocated}"
        toggleSelectListener="#{apCreditNoteTransactionBean.onToggleSelect}"
        selectRowListener="#{apCreditNoteTransactionBean.onRowSelect}" unselectRowListener="#{apCreditNoteTransactionBean.onRowUnSelect}"
        rowSelectUpdateId=":#{p:component('alloc')}"
    /> 
</h:panelGroup>
```

The problem is when unselecting the row it throws error as :

Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'onRowUnSelect' not found on type beans.APCreditNoteTransactionBean

Where I have defined the method in bean:

```
public void onRowUnSelect(UnselectEvent event) {

}
```

But this works fine if rowUnselectCheckbox listener is directly assigned from managed bean as

```
<p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" listener="#{apCreditNoteTransactionBean.onRowUnSelect}" update="#{cc.attrs.rowSelectUpdateId}" />
```

But other events: toggleSelect and rowSelectCheckBox causing the following error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.convertArgs(AstValue.java:303)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:257)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:277)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeMethodExpression.invoke(ContextualCompositeMethodExpression.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl$AttributeLookupMethodExpression.invoke(TagAttributeImpl.java:477)
    at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:53)
    at org.primefaces.event.ToggleSelectEvent.processListener(ToggleSelectEvent.java:40)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:804)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1086)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```